# if $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n}=x$ prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n}^s=x^s$ s∈Q

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n}=x$ prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n}^s=x^s$, n is natural of course. s∈Q

This is what I think is right:

let $s=\frac{p}{q}$ and so:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n}^{p/q}={\sqrt[q]{x}}^P$

Proof:

We can use this property of limits: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(x)g(x)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(x)}*\lim_{n\to\infty}{g(x)}$

we can then say $f(x)= {a_n}^{\frac{1}{q}}$ and $g(x)={a_n}^p$

We know the limits of f(x) and g(x) so now we just bring it all together.

Is this right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can't assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^p = x^p$ for any $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, it may be the point of the question to show this. What values can $s$ take? If its all $s \in \mathbb{R}$, then your solution has only covered $s \in \mathbb{Q}$. Another issue is if $x<0$, then (assuming you're only considering real sequences), $x^s$ may not be well defined for all $s$. Try using the definition of a limit for $s \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What is $s$ in the title?

Comment: Sorry I should have said this in the question: s∈Q

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution which might be a bit of an overkill but is on the other hand a very general and powerful result. There's a theorem which states:

If $f$ is a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ and $\{a_n\}$ is a convergent sequence with $a_n\in X,\;\forall n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\in X$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right).$$

*Proof:* If $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and we call $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ then we know that
$$\forall\epsilon\>0\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\;|a_n-a|\leq\epsilon,\;\forall n\geq N,$$
and if $f$ is continuous on $X$ then using the [Weierstrass continuity condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit) we have, for any $x_0\in X$, that if $\lim_{x\to\ x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$ then
$$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0:\;|x-x_0|\leq\delta\;\Rightarrow\;|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq\epsilon.$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$ and the idea is that since $\{a_n\}$ is convergent there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n-a|$ becomes arbitrary small and so since $f$ is also continuous whenever $|a_n-a|\leq\delta$, we have that $|f(a_n)-f(a)|\leq\epsilon$, as desired.

Now let $f(x)=x^s$, for $x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and the result folows directly for all $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ (or even for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$).

This then also means that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$ for any sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{a_n}=e^a$ and so forth for all continuous functions and all convergent sequences with appropriate domains.